# PyQt4 uic Compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, pyqt4, pip, tortoisehg, macports

System Information

1. Macosx 10.8.4
2. Macports 2.2.0
3. py27-pyqt4 @4.10.2_2 (active)
4. qt4-mac @4.8.5_0 (active)
5. qscintilla @2.7.2_0 (active)
6. python27 @2.7.5_1+universal (active)

Hi all,

I get the following error message:

> ImportError: No module named PyQt4.uic.Compiler

when attempting to install Tortoisehg with the following command:

> sudo pip install thg-mac

I think I've setup my $PATH correctly too. Here's the echoed output:

> /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a mac user, but this information may help you debug.

On debian, the uic module is provided by a package called pyqt4-dev-tools, not pyqt4 itself.